# Побитовые операции(Си)

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Добрый вечер,может, кто подскажет в чем ошибка в коде. Было дано задание:
Составить программу, которая вводит составные части структуры данных, приведенной в  индивидуальном задание, и формирует из них заданную упакованную структуру. Вариант задания:
[image: Мой вариант:]

```
printf("Введите тип операции (0/1) >");
scanf("%d",&o);
printf("Введите код области диска (0...3) >");
scanf("%d",&aa);
printf("Введите возможное реагирование на ошибку (0...7) >");
scanf("%d",&rrr);
printf("Введите номер диска (0...225) >");
scanf("%d",&dd);
UnitStateWord=((unsigned char)o&0x1)<<15;
        UnitStateWord|=((unsigned char)aa&3)<<13;
UnitStateWord|=((unsigned char)rrr&7)<<10;
UnitStateWord|=(0)<<9;
        UnitStateWord|=(1)<<8;
        UnitStateWord|=(dd&0xFF);
     printf("\n Cлово состояния прибора = %04x\n",UnitStateWord);
```

'
[image: Результат работы программы:]

Неверный результат получается, при вводе 127 должно было выйти 01FF,в чем ошибка не понимаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: а почему бы не использовать битовые поля?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Потому что они для этого ни в коем случае не предназначены. Это, будет  наверное, самый яркий пример неправильного использования битовых полей.

Comment: "при вводе 127 должно было выйти 01FF"? С чего бы это вдруг??? Согласно постановке задачи при номере диска `127` результат должен оканчиваться именно на `7F`, а не на `FF`.

Comment: AnT, извиняюсь, там должно быть без 7. Я просто не убрала, у меня до этого стояло <<7. Но убрала т.е вконце не имеет смысла.

Comment: Приведенный вами код, будучи дополненным до выполнимого, на таком входе выводит `d17f`, что является правильным результатом. Откуда вы взяли ваше `017f` или `01FF` мне в упор не ясно. В любом случае, приводите реальный код. Вы нас обманываете: то, что вы привели, это не то, что вы запускали. Не надо обманывать.

Comment: @AnT https://pastebin.com/A6c2V3kH - вот код полностью. При вводе тех данных что на скрине - выходит 017F, никак не D17F

Comment: @AnT, и почему же не предназначены? На мой взгляд, это как раз их прямое предназначение.

Comment: Учтите, что нолики таким образом (операцией `|=`) *не устанавливаются*. Они только сохраняются. Данный код будет работать, поскольку при установке начального значения `UnitStateWord=((unsigned char)o&0x1)<<15;` остальные поля обнуляются. Для установки поля переменной `v` без изменения других полей  в значение `field_value` размером `field_len` бит, начинающегося с позиции `field_beg` используется операция `v = (v & ~(((1 << field_len) - 1) << field_beg)) | (field_value << field_beg);`

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ни в коем случае. Спецификация языка никак не оговаривает расположение/упаковку в памяти битовых полей. Поэтому пытаться  "попасть" битовыми полями во внешнюю спецификацию, типа описания аппаратного регистра - странное и бессмысленное занятие.  Битовые поля были придуманы для экономии памяти, а не для маппинга аппаратных регистров.

Comment: @AnT Как я понимаю, в С точно так же. Но как тогда быть с огромным количеством кода, который этим пользуется? Более того, в куче книг именно это советуется - накладывать битовые поля на регистры или там при чтении из портов и т.п. Как я понимаю, тот компилятор, который эту совместимость не выдержит - будет, скажем так, очень не популярен :)

Comment: @AnT Забавно, что Страуструп в своей книге пишет дословно следующее: *As mentioned, the hardware interface is one area where bits occur frequently.
Typically, an interface is defined as a mixture of bits and numbers of various sizes.
These “bits and numbers” are typically named and occur in specific positions of a
word, often called a device register. C++ has a specific language facility to deal with
such fixed layouts: bitfields. Consider a page number as used in the page manager
deep in an operating system. Here is a diagram...*, ну, и разбирает конкретный пример.

Answer (score 4):

В вашем полном коде вы понаобъявляли переменных типа `char`/`unsigned char`

```
char o; 
char aa; 
char rrr;
unsigned char dd;
```

(Кстати, почему вдруг `char`? а в конце вдруг `unsigned char`? Что за каша?)

После чего вы их читаете при помощи `%d` в `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &o);
```

Это уже неправильно. Поведение вашего кода не определено. Неудивительно, что он выдает чепуху. Формат `%d` в `scanf` требует аргумента типа `int *`, а не `char *`. Современный компилятор должен был вам об этом сказать.

Если вы хотите использовать именно переменные типа `char`/`unsigned char`, что читать их придется через `%hhd`/`%hhu` а не через `%d`. Но я бы вам советовал не заниматься ерундой, а придать всем переменным тип `unsigned int` и работать только с ним. Чтение делать через `%u`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!